# Are defined strings set to all NULLs?

Tags: c, c-strings

I could have sworn that I read that a string that was defined but not initialized was set to all NULLs. In other words, that

```
char string[10];
```

consisted of 10 null characters, and that

```
char string[10] = "Kevin";
```

consists of the letters 'K', 'e', 'v', 'i', 'n' and five nulls.

Is this true:

1. Always?
2. Sometimes, depending on the compiler?
3. Never?

Comment: `static` (or global) arrays without initializer are initialized to all zeros. Local arrays with partial initializers are filling with zeros the uninitialized part. Local arrays without any initializer are having indeterminate values.

Comment: My guess is that you read that `char string[10] = "";` initializes the entire array to NUL characters, but you've forgotten about the empty string that's needed to make that happen.

Comment: If you rely on an initialization to zero, make it explicit.  There is no need to require the reader to remember edge cases and specific rules, and no reason for you to rely on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in other words, that char string[10]; consisted of 10 null characters,

That depends *where* and on the variable.

```
char here_yes[10]; // 10 '\0' characters
int main() {
    char here_no[10]; // 10 unknown garbage values
    static char but_here_also_yes[10]; // also 10 '\0' characters
}
```

> and that char string[10] = "Kevin"; consists of the letters 'K', 'e', 'v', 'i', 'n' and five nulls. Is this true: Always?

Yes. If you partially initialize a string or a variable, the rest is filled with `'\0'` or zeros.

```
char this_has_10_nulls[10] = "";
int main() {
    char this_has_ab_followed_by_8_nulls[10] = { 'a', 'b' };
    static char this_has_Kevin_followed_by_5_nulls[10] = "Kevin";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear examples and answer.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no initializer present (as in your first example), then *all* elements of the array will have indeterminate values. From [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ##### 6.7.9 Initialization
>
> …
> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

However, if you provide *any* sort of initializer (as in your second example), then any elements in the array that aren't *explicitly* set will be initialized to zero. From a few paragraphs later in the Standard:

> 21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
> are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
> string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
> are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
> initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
> duration.

(Note that a `char` of static storage duration will be initialized to zero.)